# iFrame in same page

Tags: html, iframe

unable to run two iframes in same page
my code

```
  <table width="100%"  border="1">
        <tr>
        <td width="33.3%" align="center"><h2>First Server</h2></td>
        <td align="center" width="33.3%" rowspan="2"><h2>Users</h2></td>
        <td width="33.3%" align="center"><h2>2nd Server</h2></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center">
          <iframe id="f1" name="f1" src="http://xx-xx.xx/xx/xx.php">
          </td>

          <td align="center"><iframe name="f2" id="f2" src="http://cc.cc/cc/cc.php"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

and the result the the first iframe 'f1' sorry for my english
btw URL work 100%

Comment: [You aren't closing your iframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe).. They should be `<iframe src="..."></iframe>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comment, you need to close your iframes - `</iframe>`.

So it would be:

```
<table width="100%"  border="1">
        <tr>
        <td width="33.3%" align="center"><h2>First Server</h2></td>
        <td align="center" width="33.3%" rowspan="2"><h2>Users</h2></td>
        <td width="33.3%" align="center"><h2>2nd Server</h2></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center">
          <iframe id="f1" name="f1" src="http://xx-xx.xx/xx/xx.php"></iframe>
          </td>

          <td align="center"><iframe name="f2" id="f2" src="http://cc.cc/cc/cc.php"></iframe></td>
```

---

[Read More](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)